# How to append a last column (1d array) to a 2d numpy array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
b = np.array([5, 6])
```

when I try to append `b` to `a` as `a`'s last column using the below code

```
 np.hstack([a, b])



it thows an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in hstack
  File "C:\Users\utkal\anaconda3\envs\AIML\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 345, in hstack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 1 dimension(s)
```

I want the final array as:

```
1 2 3 5
4 5 6 6
```

Comment: `b` isn't a column.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```py
np.hstack((a,b.reshape(2,1)))
array([[1, 2, 3, 5],
       [4, 5, 6, 6]])
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.hstack` is a shortcut for `np.concatenate` on axis=1. So, it requires both arrays have the same shapes with all dimensions matching except on concatenate axis. In your case, you need both array in 2-d and matching on dimension `0`

So you need

```
np.hstack([a, b[:,None]])

Out[602]:
array([[1, 2, 3, 5],
       [4, 5, 6, 6]])
```

Or use `np.concatenate`

```
np.concatenate([a, b[:,None]], axis=1)

Out[603]:
array([[1, 2, 3, 5],
       [4, 5, 6, 6]])
```